# priority queue modification in Python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, priority-queue

I would like to implement a derivative of a priority queue like in the following. A traditional priority queue a la `from queue import PriorityQueue` stores the data as the following (assuming tuples of the form `(priority, value)`

```
#pseudocode
queue = ((1, obj1), (1, obj2), (2, obj3), (3, obj4) ...)
```

If I have many workers processing the objects in the queue e.g. 10 workers running `func(obj)` then I think there's a possibility that a worker will start processing `obj3` before `obj2` finishes completing

However, `func(obj)` may place more objects into the priority queue but **only at the same priority of the object the function is currently processing**. Is there any way to ensure that all objects of priority N are completed before moving on to objects of priority > N?

For example `func(obj2)` may insert another object into the queue `(1, obj2_1)` but if another worker picks up `obj3` before `obj2` finishes processing then `obj2_1` with priority 1 may finish processing after `obj3` which has priority 2 - I would like to ensure that all objects of priority 1 are processed before priority 2 etc

Comment: Yes, it's possible that a worker could start processing obj3 before processing of obj2 is complete. What you're asking is possible, but it's going to leave a lot of workers idle, waiting for all priority 1 objects' processing to complete before starting on any priority 2 objects. This is a fairly unusual requirement. Are you sure you have to do that?

Comment: yes it's an unusual requirement but afraid it is necessary - do you know of any good implementations?

Comment: Beyond writing a wrapper that keeps track of the highest current priority and only allows processing of items with equal or higher priority, no. That implementation doesn't look especially difficult. but I haven't done it.